# In a list, if I break inheritance will Site collection Admin be able to access that list?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have one doubt, In a SharePoint 2013 list, if I break inheritance will Site Collection Admin be able to access that list ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer here:

https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/what-is-a-sharepoint-site-collection-administrator/

The SharePoint Site Collection Administrator cannot be locked out of any subsite, list, library, item, or page on the site. The permissions inheritance for any of these elements can be broken at any time, and permissions changed so that even users with Full Control rights have lesser permissions or even no permissions at all. In all cases the SharePoint Site Collection Administrator will always have full access to all of the elements and all of the data. This is especially handy when a site Owner accidentally deletes their own user account or group when creating custom permissions!